# How would I be able to catch two variables in one method? C#

Tags: c#, list, scope

So my question is how would I be able to use the ChooseCity Method for naming Cities within the Cities Method considering I'm already catching an array in its parameters. Also I wasn't completely sure on how to simply call the next one in the list vs picking a random one out.
This is C# code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<string> nameCities = new List<string> { "Murcia", "Alicante", "Valencia", "Granada", "Albacete" };

        Cities(Inventory);
    }


    static void Cities(int[] Inventory)
    {
        InitializeConsoleWindow();

        Console.WriteLine(" You are now in the city of {0}", ChooseCity(nameCities, random) + " ");

        DisplayReturnPrompt();
    }

    private static string ChooseCity(List<string> nameCities, Random random)
    {
        int index = random.Next(nameCities.Count);
        string chosenCity = nameCities[index];
        nameCities.RemoveAt(index);
        return chosenCity;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please mention what programming language this is.

Comment: @Juhana Thank you, I didn't notice I didn't mention that.

Comment: @Pachelbel It actually was this, I just initially tried it and it didn't work.  What made it work was to make both the list and random into public statics.

Comment: Also thank you @User1334007 for all the work you put in, That was pretty close to what I was looking for.  And sorry to everyone for the unclearity of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what you wish to accomplish. Is your problem that you cannot access the variables you declared in your `Main` method? Then you should put them outside, e.g like this:

```
class Program
{

    static Random random = new Random();
    static List<string> nameCities =  new List<string> { "Murcia", ...};
    ...
```

In this way these variables are available to all your static methods of `Program`. However, for more advanced programs, I'd try to avoid the excessive use of static methods and variables.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't terribly clear, I'm pretty new to programming.  Sorry.  Anyways the method Madrid(int[] Inventory) already has the parameter of " int[] Inventory" in the parenthesis.  So I was confused as to how to bring the "chosenCity" string into the Madrid method. I return it at the end of its own method "return chosenCity;" however I'm not sure how to catch it with Madrid.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether I understand - would you like to add another parameter to Madrid()? Maybe you could add a small description of what your program actually ought to do to your original post.

Comment: I meant to say method Cities(int[] Inventory), and yes I need to simply make  this work: Console.WriteLine(" You are now in the city of {0}", ChooseCity(nameCities, random) + " ");

Comment: This line does not work since nameCities and random are not known in the Cities method (they are local to Main) - so maybe you should really try to transform these two variables into static class variables?

Comment: so just make a class and put both of those variables in it along with the ChooseCity method?  For example later I could call the line  Console.WriteLine(" You are now in the city of {0}", AClassName.ChooseCity(nameCities, random) + " ");

Do you think that would work?

Comment: If it is fitting for the design of your program :) You could also try the example suggested by me in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to get a feel for what you're trying to accomplish. What exactly do you want the code to do?

I'm going out on a limb here and assuming you are attempting to present the user with a list of cities, let them choose one of the options, and display their choice. Assuming I'm somewhere in the ballpark, here is some code that does that in a loop until all your city choices are gone:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> nameCities = new List<string> { "Murcia", "Alicante", "Valencia", "Granada", "Albacete" };

        Cities(nameCities);
        Console.WriteLine("All out of cities. Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Cities(List<string> cities)
    {
        while (cities.Count > 0)
            ChooseCity(cities);
    }

    private static void ChooseCity(List<string> cities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Which city would you like to choose?\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < cities.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", i, cities[i]);

        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int idx;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out idx) && idx >= 0 && idx < cities.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou have chosen {0}\n", cities[idx]);
            cities.RemoveAt(idx);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid option");
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I have to pass the `cities` variable from `Main` into `Cities` then into `ChooseCity`. This is because variables declared inside `Main` are local to that method and other methods will not be able to see them. So you either have to pass those variable as arguments to the other methods as I have done here or give them more global scope (like maybe make them class member variables).